# Ruby conditional assignment

Tags: ruby

What is the Ruby way to assign a variable a to another variable b if a is superior to b ?

I have three possibilities so far :

- `if a > b then a = b  end`
- `a = b if a > b`
- `a = a > b ? b : a`

More broadly, is there a way to set an upper limit to a variable ? 
**e.g:** if I try to set a = 50 and a has an upper limit of 25, a will be equal to 25 after assignment.

Comment: From your question it seems like you want `b = a` if `a > b`, but in your code snippets you're doing `a = b` if `a > b`. Which is it?

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you ask for the upper limit:

```
UPPER_LIMIT = 25
b = 100
a = [b, UPPER_LIMIT].min
```

`a` will always smaller or equal to `25`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this solution, however, it seems unnecessary to use arrays to solve a simple greater-than problem.

Comment: @Linuxios agreed! But I think JahMyst asking for something that Ruby-ist style, so I have to come up with this :p

Answer (score 5):

All three options work, it's just a question of style.

I'd go with number 2. It most clearly communicates your intent, while avoiding extraneous keywords (number 1) or excessively terse one liners (number 3).

In answer to your more general question, there is no way to override variable assignment in Ruby. You can override assignment to instance variables using setter methods though. If you just want to do it afterwords, the code from your question is sufficient:

```
a = something
a = 25 if a > 25
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `a > b && a = b`

where `b` is that upper limit.

```
b = 25
a = 25
a > b && a = b #> false; a = 25
a = 26 
a > b && a = b #> true; a = 25
```

Comment: Clever short circuiting, but a little terse for a simple problem, no?

Comment: Maybe ... I've seen `condition && conditional_expression` as a pretty common pattern on the only big rails project I've worked on - but if it isn't already established as a pattern in the project, then yes it would be a little obfuscating

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it -- it's just overly terse and difficult to understand for a language where in as many characters you can write `a = b if a > b`. One of things I love about Ruby is the ability to use an `if` conditional as an expression.

Comment: Thanks! But this is the other thing I love about Ruby -- 1 million ways to do everything.

Comment: @Linuxios, you probably won't like this one any better: `a =  (a+b+(a<=>b)*(b-a))/2`. You are too kind. My view: alexanderbird's answer (and my answer) should have their heads cut off (the answers', not the authors'.)  What's the point of obfuscatiion when there's a simple, straightforward, easy-to-understand way of doing this?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I now have an image of you using a guillotine to cut the upvote buttons off of answers. Maybe we should propose that on Meta...

Answer (score 1):

Try: `b = a > b ? a : b`

It's the same as writing:

```
if a > b
  b = a
else
  b = b
end
```